# Negative subscript error when subsetting to positive numbers in R

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to convert all positive numbers to uppercase letters and all negative numbers to lowercase letters but am getting a negative subscript error and it is unclear why.

Here is some example code:

```
x = -1:1
ifelse(x > 0, letters[x], "XXX")
```

I assumed the output would look like

```
"XXX", "XXX", "a"
```

But instead get a negative subscript error.

### Any idea why this comes up?

Altering the example to represent the text of the problem.
The goal is to have letters greater than 0 incrementally increasing uppercase letters and values from 0 and below incrementally increasing negative letters.

```
x = -2:2
ifelse(x > 0, LETTERS[x], letters[x])
```

Should give

```
c, b, a, A, B
```

Comment: Try `ifelse(x > 0, letters[which.min(x>0)], "XXX")`

Comment: how would this accomodate negative numbers if we extend to the second argument in ifelse? e.g. the result being a, a, A instead (assuming 0 is negative for this example)

Comment: So 0 is also `a` and -1 is also `a` ? How will that work?

Comment: you are right. I will re-write to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is `ifelse` doesn't send partial `x` values in `yes` and `no` part of `ifelse` while executing code. You could use scalar `if`/`else` with `for` loop which would work as expected.

To use vectorised functions an alternative would be :

```
c('XXX', letters)[ifelse(x > 0, x + 1, 1)]
#[1] "XXX" "XXX" "a
```

Or without `ifelse` :

```
c('XXX', letters)[pmax(x + 1, 1)]
```

---

For a general case you can use :

```
x = -2:2
all_combos <- c(rev(letters), LETTERS)
all_combos[x + length(letters)]
#[1] "c" "b" "a" "A" "B"
```

The logic is to change the negative index to positive by adding the `length` of negative values to `x`.

Comment: Could this extend to negative numbers being lowercase and positive numbers being uppercase?

Comment: I updated the answer for such cases.

Answer (score 1):

`ifelse` has the following form:

```
ifelse(test, yes, no)
```

Internally, `ifelse` first evaluates the values of "yes" and "no" as given, and then uses "test" to determine where these values should appear in the output vector. In your example, the value of "yes" first evaluates to `letters[c(-1, 0, 1)]`, which mixes negative and positive subscripts, and throws an error.